# How to fix this error [object Object] in my code

Tags: javascript

I get this error [object Object] in my conditions alarms (bool) and i don't know how to fix it. Must show 1 or 0.

If you need the php code i can put here. 
I don't know how to fix this code and why give me that error.

See the image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo1qi.jpg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.updateInnerViewTimer = setInterval(periodicTaskDebug, 1000);
    function periodicTaskDebug() {
        for (var key in window.equipmentState.Parameters) {
            if ($('#' + key)) {
                if (key === 'debugStartupTime') {
                    var d = new Date(0); // 0 sets the date to the epoch
                    d.setUTCSeconds(window.equipmentState.Parameters[key]);
                    $('#' + key).filter('.debug').text(d)
                } else {
                    $('#' + key).filter('.debug').text(Math.round(100 * window.equipmentState.Parameters[key]) / 100);
                }

                if ($('#' + key).attr("boolean") !== "yes") {
                    if (window.equipmentState.Parameters[key] === "NaN" || window.equipmentState.Parameters[key] <= 0) {
                        $('#' + key).filter('.debug').css("color", "red");
                    } else {
                        $('#' + key).filter('.debug').css("color", "blue");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (var key in window.equipmentState.Alarms) {
            $('#' + key).text(window.equipmentState.Alarms[key]);
            if (window.equipmentState.Alarms[key]) {
                $('#' + key).filter('.debug').css("color", "red");
            } else {
                $('#' + key).filter('.debug').css("color", "blue");
            }
        }

        for (var key in window.equipmentState.ConditionAlarms) {
            $('#' + key).text(window.equipmentState.ConditionAlarms[key]);
            if (window.equipmentState.ConditionAlarms[key]) {
                $('#' + key).css('.debug').css("color", "red");
            } else {
                $('#' + key).css('.debug').css("color", "blue");
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[object Object] is the default toString representation of an object in javascript.

As you are dealing with jQuery objects, you might want to do

```
console.log(alarm()[0].id);
```